# Spring task scheduler + jboss

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss

I'm having an strange behavior with spring task schedule on jboss 6.3.0.GA. I don't know why everytime when a task is launched in jboss it's launched twice at same time, in tomcat just once a time.

```
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="1"/>
    <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="taskScheduler">
        <task:scheduled ref="jobListener" method="pickUpChanges" cron="*/5 * * * * ?"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

spring.version: 3.1.1.RELEASE

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have both scheduler corn expression and fixed-delay remove one of them.

```
<task:scheduled ref="jobListener" method="pickUpChanges" cron="*/5 * * * * ?"/>
```

or

```
<task:scheduled ref="jobListener" method="pickUpChanges" fixed-delay="3000"/>
```

Refer the [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-namespace-scheduled-tasks) for more detials. In short in your case two triggers are triggered  one for fixed-delay and other for cron expression resulting in two times execution of the method.

Comment: Yes, Thanks, I'm using just cron the other was just a test but a put it here. Just using cron execute the method twice.